# I need correct example for ajax send and received data in zend framework 3

Tags: ajax, zend-framework3

Example for send and received data between ajax function and action of controller in Zend framework 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of an ajax request using ZF3. You may give a try with this one. In this example we would use ZF3's default `Application` module.

Lets assume we would retrieve data via a ajax call from the following url.

```
http://yoursite.com/title
```

Lets create an action method for the `title` route in the `IndexController`.

```
public function titleAction()
{
    // Initialize view
    $view = new ViewModel();

    // Checks if this is a Javascript request
    $xmlHttpRequst = $this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest();

    if (! $xmlHttpRequst) {
        die('Bad request');
    }

    /**
     * Here we may pull data from database but for tests
     * here we make an array of titles for the view
     */
    $titles = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $titles[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor {$i}";
    }

    // Set data to be used in the view
    $view->setVariable('titles', $titles);

    /**
     * Tell the renderer not to show the layout
     * by setting setTerminal to true
     */
    $view->setTerminal(true);

    return $view;        
}
```

We created a method, we need creating a view template for it.

**view/application/index/title.phtml**

```
<?php 
foreach ($titles as $title) {
    echo '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>';
}
```

Now we would create another action method in the `IndexController` from where we would make the ajax call.

```
http://yoursite.com/text
```

So lets make that action method too...

```
public function textAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

and view template would be like so

**view/application/index/text.phtml**

```
<h1>Handling ajax request</h1>

<button onclick="showTitle()">Show Title</button>

<div id="box"></div>

<?php
    // Set url   
    $url = $this->serverUrl('/title'); // http://yoursite.com/title

    // This is for the "url" catch
    echo "<script>" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "\tvar url = '{$url}';" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "</script>" . PHP_EOL;
?>

<script>
    function showTitle() {
        $.get(url, function(data){
            $('#box').html(data);
        })
        .done(function(){
            console.log('Done!');
        })
        .fail(function(){
            console.log('Failed!');
        });      
    }
</script>
```

This script needs jQuery Javascript library to make the ajax call. So make sure that script is added in your view/layout/layout.phtml.

The last thing we need is to set up routes for the `/title` and `/text`. Lets add those two routes to the route section of module/Application/config/module.config.php

```
'title' => [
    'type' => Literal::class,
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/title',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
            'action' => 'title',
        ],
    ],
],
'text' => [
    'type' => Literal::class,
    'options' => [
        'route' => '/text',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
            'action' => 'text',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Let us know if it makes you happy!

Comment: it's worked well but I wanna show example for ajax I can't send or received data between ajax and action